# QGIS 3.8 labels placement

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

On my layer the setting of the labels is:

[image: label configuring]

But all the labels do not appear, as if there was a limit on the number.

Sample with some features

[image: Sample with some features]

Sample with all features:
[image: Sample with all features]

some labels have disappeared such as 1, 3, 4.

Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Remove the option "supress labels smaller than 1mm"

Comment: It's hard to see how many layers you're playing with ... Are the "big" black squares the same layer as the smaller ones ? I suppose that's not the case ...

Comment: I tried different settings of the unsuccessful option "supress labels smaller than 1mm" .

Comment: The small black squares is the debug label placement.